# Is it possible to force a buffer refresh in JAWS 9 or 10?

Tags: ajax, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

Is there some way, through either JAWS scripting or HTML, to force JAWS to refresh its virtual screen buffer (normally <kbd>Ins</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>)?  I'm working on an AJAX-heavy web application that requires JAWS support, but the users don't particularly like the solution "hit <kbd>Ins</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> after performing any action to catch possible changes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is through Jaws scripting. According to the script documentation

```
Refresh (1)
```

Will force a refresh of the screen and

```
Refresh (0)
```

will only refresh if needed.
There's also a RefreshWindow(Handle) that refreshes the window with the given handle but I don't know how well that will work in an internet browser since I'm not sure weather all the content you need is in one window.

Comment: After doing some reading this looks like it will probably do the trick (or at least get as close as I'm going to get).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than refreshing the entire JAWS virtual buffer and doing something that is JAWS-specific, I would recommend using the [ARIA `aria-live` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/complete#aria-live) for this. Place it on an element which contains dynamic content, i.e. which you update with JavaScript, and the portion of the JAWS virtual buffer corresponding to that element will be automatically updated when you change the content of the element.